Using reflection to set a private field, no error but field always old value
I'm using ASP.NET with default session storage and HttpContext.Session is returning an instance of DistributedSession (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/Session/src/DistributedSession.cs).
This appears to load all session values once and there is a private field _loaded which needs to be set to false if I want LoadAsync to actually load from storage again.
Session is working as expected so there's nothing wrong with the configuration.
Obviously this is bad practice and there is another suitable solution, but ignore the requirement I'm more interested in why the private field keeps failing to hold the value I'm setting?
    public class SomeClass
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

        public SomeClass(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }

        private async Task SomeMethod()
        {
            var session = _accessor.HttpContext.Session;

            var loadedFlag = session.GetType().GetField("_loaded", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            loadedFlag.SetValue(session, false); // doesn't throw

            var isLoaded = loadedFlag.GetValue(session); // still true?

            await session.LoadAsync();
        }
    }


Seems to work fine?

@NPras I think the code is fine, however when running in context of an actual web application, it doesn't update the session object.  screen shot

@Ant: the posted code is not the same as the one in the screenshot. In the latter you evaluate _accessor.HttpContext.Session three times as opposed to the OP where you cache it into a session variable. Are you sure HttpContext.Session returns always the same instance, and it doesn't set the _loaded field?

I believe this is due to passing in value type (i.e. false) instead of boxing it as an object (also not great, but yeh... it is what it is).
object boxedValue = (object)false;
loadedFlag.SetValue(session, boxedValue); // hopefully still doesn't throw
var isLoaded = loadedFlag.GetValue(session); // hopefully now false?

From the doc

For example, if the field's type is Boolean, an instance of Object with the appropriate Boolean value is passed


Hmmm it's still not working, I'm beginning to think the code is correct but there is some other issue at play here preventing me from updating the session object.  Perhaps it is restricted in some way? Quick screen share of debugging here

As if I create my own class with a private field and apply the same code it does update the value correctly.  It's just when I try and apply a change to the session object using HttpContextAccessor.

It is odd, and my initial suspicion is way off - it might be worth disabling Just My Code in VS and setting some breakpoints to see what's happening. Random question, have you added the distributed memory cache on startup?

Http context session object is resolving to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession and is working with simple values set/get between requests. 
